# Unix: What does cat by itself do?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I saw the line `data=$(cat)` in a bash script (just declaring an empty variable) and am mystified as to what that could possibly do.

I read the man pages, but it doesn't have an example or explanation of this.  Does this capture stdin or something?  Any documentation on this?

EDIT: Specifically how the heck does doing `data=$(cat)` allow for it to run this hook script?

```
#!/bin/bash 

# Runs all executable pre-commit-* hooks and exits after, 
# if any of them was not successful. 
# 
# Based on 
# http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-01/msg00308.html 

data=$(cat) 
exitcodes=() 
hookname=`basename $0` 

# Run each hook, passing through STDIN and storing the exit code. 
# We don't want to bail at the first failure, as the user might 
# then bypass the hooks without knowing about additional issues. 

for hook in $GIT_DIR/hooks/$hookname-*; do 
   test -x "$hook" || continue 
   echo "$data" | "$hook" 
   exitcodes+=($?) 
 done
```

https://github.com/henrik/dotfiles/blob/master/git_template/hooks/pre-commit

Comment: Do you have a different man page than I do? Because I hit page down twice on a _very_ short man page before I came to the line: "cat  --  Copy standard input to standard output" under Examples. A brief command line test confirms this is exactly what it does invoked with 0 arguments.

Comment: I've rolled back your recent edit. The way to indicate that your question has been answered is to accept an answer.

Comment: Get quite hungry because it can't operate the tin opener.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`cat` will catenate its input to its output.

In the context of the variable capture you posted, the effect is to assign the statement's (or containing script's) standard input to the variable.

The command substitution `$(command)` will return the command's output; the assignment will assign the substituted string to the variable; and in the absence of a file name argument, `cat` will read and print standard input.

The Git hook script you found this in captures the commit data from standard input so that it can be repeatedly piped to each hook script separately. You only get one copy of standard input, so if you need it multiple times, you need to capture it somehow. (I would use a temporary file, and quote all file name variables properly; but keeping the data in a variable is certainly okay, especially if you only expect fairly small amounts of input.)

Answer (score 5):

Doing:

```
t@t:~# temp=$(cat)    
hello how
are you?
t@t:~# echo $temp
hello how are you?
```

(A single <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> on the line by itself following "are you?" terminates the input.)

As manual says

> cat - concatenate files and print on the standard output

Also

> cat    Copy standard input to standard output.

here, `cat` will concatenate your `STDIN` into a single string and assign it to variable `temp`.

Comment: This coincidentally also illustrates what happens when you don't quote the arguments to `echo`. You want `echo "$temp"` unless you specifically require the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the value of `$temp`.

Answer (score 4):

Say your bash script `script.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
data=$(cat)
```

Then, the following commands will store the string `STR` in the variable `data`:

1. `echo STR | bash script.sh`
2. `bash script.sh < <(echo STR)`
3. `bash script.sh <<< STR`